# Only output certain cells from .csv file into textbox windows form C++cli

Tags: c++-cli

I have a csv file with thousands of rows. However I want my program to read the first line on startbtn but only output certain cells. So for example my csv file has this in row 1:

test 1  test 2  test 3  1stat  ignore test 1  test 2  test 3  1stat  ignore

But I want my textbox to show only cells 1, 5 and 6 for example so my textbox looks like this:

test 1

ignore

test 1

The code I have so far is this:

```
    private: System::Void StartBtn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
 String^ fileName = "same_para_diff_uprn.csv";
 StreamReader^ din = File::OpenText(fileName);
  String^ str;
  str = din->ReadLine();
 array<Char>^chars = {','};
   array<String^>^split = str->Split( chars );
   IEnumerator^ myEnum = split->GetEnumerator();
     while ( myEnum->MoveNext() )
   {
      String^ s = safe_cast<String^>(myEnum->Current);

     if (  !s->Trim()->Equals( "" ) )


          textBox1->Text += gcnew String (s);



             }
             }
```

TIA

Comment: The first step would be to make your code actually readable by indenting it properly.

Comment: and the 2nd step would be to edit your question instead of posting an answer... ;-)  Due to your follow-up question I guess that this one is already obsolete.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read next line in csv file on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460546/how-to-read-next-line-in-csv-file-on-button-click)

Answer (score 0):

```
    String^ fileName = "same_para_diff_uprn1.csv";
 StreamReader^ din = File::OpenText(fileName);


  String^ delimStr = ",";

   array<Char>^ delimiter = delimStr->ToCharArray( );
   array<String^>^ words;
   String^ str = din->ReadLine();


words = str->Split( delimiter );



     textBox1->Text += gcnew String (words[10]);
     textBox1->Text += gcnew String ("\r\n");
```